# AlphaMasked Images showing up with pink instead of texture (Cycles) V 2.78

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor, image

I'm trying to create a nature scene with some plants which require alpha-masked images for the leaves. But whenever I UV unwrap them, the objects get coloured pink.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the *Cycles Renderer* is set as the render engine.
[image: Cycles Renderer[1]]

A pink color in texture view means, that there are missing images. You probably moved your Blender file to another directory or changed paths of image textures.

Go into textured mode in the *3D View*. In the node editor select the desired *image texture* node.

[image: cant load image node]

If the source path is not found, the message "Can't Load Image" will be displayed. Click on the folder icon to locate your image file (marked green).

Comment: @Sarsha. If this did solve your problem, you should mark the answer as accepted by clicking the check mark on the left.

Comment: @Leander it still does not work, It works for other textures but it's got some problem with Alpha masked images. it can be found and when in texture view or material view i can see it, however in Rendered view or in the final Render it shows up as the pink colour. I do not believe it is the image missing as it is implemented onto the plane according to the texture view.

Comment: Are you only using a single material. A single texture? It would be easier if you posted a screenshot of your node setup. Edit your question or ask a new one.