# Why is a purple light/texture appearing in rendered view?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I'm rendering a low-poly building/skyscraper for a city that I am creating. I have been following this [Blender Guru tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCEN0qQOsIA&index=1&t=1542s&list=PLCClUX1UWKR7a0VANjbd4DWM7jw7jcRZN)  on YouTube and my models and textures have been looking great, but now when I go to render cycles is appearing weird with a black background and a pink shading. Here's a screenshot:[image: Screenshot of problem] I understand that my lighting isn't great yet, but I don't understand the pink colors.

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Pink means two things: either the texture is unavailable (it was not saved as an image or it was moved to a different folder or deleted). Or is mapped incorrectly and blender cannot display it

Comment: also realted: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27105/texture-appears-pink-in-blender-render/27108#27108 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65058/alphamasked-images-showing-up-with-pink-instead-of-texture-cycles-v-2-78

Answer (score 0):

It was because I had moved the textures to a new folder. Oops. 
and you have to link it back......find the texture location